# How does pandas Dataframe.loc accept the [...] syntax?

Tags: python, pandas

I have read this documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

You can use a syntax like `df.loc[df['shield'] > 6, ['max_speed']]`.

I tried using Github and found out:

Suppose you have a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` object, i.e. a `DataFrame` called `df`.

The type of `df.loc` is `pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer`.

Nevertheless, I could not sort out these questions:

1. How do you make a Python function/class accepting a syntax like above?
2. Where in the source code of `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` is the property `self.loc` defined??

Comment: Look at this file on github. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py and this
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/61362be9ea4d69b33ae421f1f98b8db50be611a2/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py#L467

Comment: @Poojan Thanks, but where does `get_loc`  become `self.loc`?? Sorry for being so stupid, but I don't get it :/

Comment: @Poojan I looked at the `get_loc` function but I cannot find  any @property decorator or any other syntax defining `self.loc`. I git cloned the pandas repo. Used `git grep -n self.loc` and `git grep -A1 @property | grep loc` but I can't find it. Could you solve my issue?

Comment: I am unable to find exact location of code where `.loc` is implemented but it is implemented somewhere in this file. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py.
Implementation of loc is more complex. You can search in `indexing.py` file for some in depth explanation . Write answer if you find a good explanation for this.

Answer (score 5):

1. How you make a class accept that syntax in general is by implementing [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) which is an example of operator overloading. This allows an object of that class to be indexed with `[]`. For example:

   ```
   class get_item_example(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
            print(key)
   ```

   Try it out:

   ```
   >>> gi = get_item_example()
   >>> gi['a']
   a
   >>> gi[['a','b','c']]
   ['a', 'b', 'c']
   >>> gi['a','b','c']
   ('a', 'b', 'c')
   ```

   In the case of `df.loc[df['shield'] > 6, ['max_speed']]` what happens is that the key passed to `__getitem__` is a tuple containing the pandas series returned by `df['shield'] > 6` and the single item list `['max_speed']`.
2. In the pandas source, `pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer` inherits an implementation of `__getitem__` from `pandas.core.indexing. _LocationIndexer`. The implementation is here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/61362be9ea4d69b33ae421f1f98b8db50be611a2/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1374

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a property that has indexer (`df.loc[]` vs. `df[]`), you can create another class that will process the indexer and that gets created and passed back when the property is accessed.

```
class Helper(self)
   def __init__(self, parent):
       self.parent = parent

   def __getitem__(self, idx):
       ### do your indexing here

class Parent(self):
   ...

   @property
   def fancy_indexer(self):
       return Helper(self)
```